# One of my Web Fonts does not render on Firefox

Tags: css, fonts, web, webfonts

I have two web fonts installed on my site and one is working on Firefox, while the other one is not. If you check it on Chrome, both of the Google web fonts work perfect.
Here is my code:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'UnitSlabProLight';
    src: url('/unitslabpro-light-webfont.eot');
    src: url('/unitslabpro-light-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('/unitslabpro-light-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('/unitslabpro-light-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('/unitslabpro-light-webfont.svg#UnitSlabProLight') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'UnitSlabProBlack';
    src: url('/unitslabpro-black-webfont.eot');
    src: url('/unitslabpro-black-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('/unitslabpro-black-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('/unitslabpro-black-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('/unitslabpro-black-webfont.svg#UnitSlabProBlack') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

Site is http://www.journeytoearth.com/

Thanks in advance for any help and solutions.

Comment: Which font is it that is not rendering?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the @font-face src property for the "UnitSlabProBlack" is absolutely linked, while your "UnitSlabProLight" src property is relative to the root.

I would suggest to try changing the UnitSlabProBlack src format to match that of the "UnitSlabProLight", since that one works.

It looks like Firefox only accepts relative links for the src: 
http://webfonts.info/wiki/index.php?title=%40font-face_support_in_Firefox

From http://www.journeytoearth.com/wp-content/themes/melville/style.css

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'UnitSlabProLight';
src: url('/unitslabpro-light-webfont.eot');
src: url('/unitslabpro-light-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('/unitslabpro-light-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('/unitslabpro-light-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('/unitslabpro-light-webfont.svg#UnitSlabProLight') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;}


@font-face {
font-family: 'UnitSlabProBlack';
src: url('http://www.journeytoearth.com/fonts/unitslabpro-black-webfont.eot');
src: url('http://www.journeytoearth.com/fonts/unitslabpro-black-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('http://www.journeytoearth.com/fonts/unitslabpro-black-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('http://www.journeytoearth.com/fonts/unitslabpro-black-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('http://www.journeytoearth.com/fonts/unitslabpro-black-webfont.svg#UnitSlabProBlack') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;}
```

Comment: Thanks for that piece of advice Waynebo. Unfortunately, I have tried that too and it didn't worked. I have actually moved the fonts from one directory to another just to test out if it will work. UnitSlabProLight works on any directory but Black doesn't. Any other solutions? Thanks.

Comment: After few  minutes of transferring the files and editing the css, my webfonts now work on FF. Anyway thanks Waynebo for the help.

Comment: Thanks Waynebo, the relative path for Firefox did the trick with my problem.

Comment: Firefox evidently blocks 'what it considers' externally hosted fonts (to prevent XSS attacks I guess).